# Python pandas create additional dataframe columns by grouping on existing column

Tags: python, pandas, filter, merge, group-by

Trying to create new dataframe columns from the contents of an existing column. Easier to explain with an example. I would like to convert this:

```html
. Yr Month Class Cost
1 2015 1 L 19.2361
2 2015 1 M 29.4723
3 2015 1 S 48.5980
4 2015 1 T 169.7630
5 2015 2 L 19.1506
6 2015 2 M 30.0886
7 2015 2 S 49.3765
8 2015 2 T 167.0000
9 2015 3 L 19.3465
10 2015 3 M 29.1991
11 2015 3 S 46.2580
12 2015 3 T 157.7916
13 2015 4 L 18.3165
14 2015 4 M 28.2314
15 2015 4 S 44.5844
16 2015 4 T 162.3241
17 2015 5 L 17.4556
18 2015 5 M 27.0434
19 2015 5 S 42.8841
20 2015 5 T 159.3457
21 2015 6 L 16.5343
22 2015 6 M 24.9853
23 2015 6 S 40.5612
24 2015 6 T 153.4902
```

...into the following so that I can plot 4 separate lines [L, M, S, T]:

```html
.  Yr   Month    L    M    S    T
1 2015 1 19.2361 29.4723 48.5980 169.7630
2 2015 2 19.1506 30.0886 49.3765 167.0000
3 2015 3 19.3465 29.1991 46.2580 157.7916
4 2015 4 18.3165 28.2314 44.5844 162.3241
5 2015 5 17.4556 27.0434 42.8841 159.3457
6 2015 6 16.5343 24.9853 40.5612 153.4902
```

I was able to work through it in what feels like a very clumsy way, by filtering the dataframe on the 'class' column... and then 3 separate merges.

```
list_class = ['L', 'M', 'S', 'T']
year = 'Yr'
month = 'Month'
df_class = pd.DataFrame()
df_class1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_class2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_class1 = merge(df[[month, year, 'Class','Cost']][df['Class']==list_class[0]], df[[month, year, 'Class','Cost']][df['Class']==list_class[1]], \
            left_on=[month, year], right_on=[month, year])
df_class2 = merge(df[[month, year, 'Class','Cost']][df['Class']==list_class[2]], df[[month, year, 'Class','Cost']][df['Class']==list_class[3]], \
            left_on=[month, year], right_on=[month, year])
df_class = merge(df_class1, df_class2, left_on=[month, year], right_on=[month, year]).groupby([year, month]).mean().plot(figsize(15,8))
```

There must be a more efficient way. Feels like it should be done with groupby, but I couldn't nail it down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first convert the `df` to a multi-level index type and then `unstack` the level `Class` will give you what you want. Suppose df is the original dataframe shown on the very beginning of your post.

```
df.set_index(['Yr', 'Month', 'Class'])['Cost'].unstack('Class')

Out[29]: 
Class             L        M        S         T
Yr   Month                                     
2015 1      19.2361  29.4723  48.5980  169.7630
     2      19.1506  30.0886  49.3765  167.0000
     3      19.3465  29.1991  46.2580  157.7916
     4      18.3165  28.2314  44.5844  162.3241
     5      17.4556  27.0434  42.8841  159.3457
     6      16.5343  24.9853  40.5612  153.4902
```

Comment: Jianxun - that's perfect! Thank you and sorry for not presenting a challenge.